# How to remove an element from a struct array which has pointers?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, data-structures

This is my structure which has two integer pointers aV and aT.

```
struct ADJP
{
    int *aV;
    int eV;
    int nV;
    int *aT;
    int nT;
};
ADJP *Umb = NULL;
```

The allocation process of aV and aT is like this..

```
    for(int i=0; i<nb; i++)
    {
        Umb[i].aV = new int[N];
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            Umb[i].aV[j] = pIn[i].aV[j];
}
```

I want to remove one specific element from Umb array. for example I want to remove Umb[5], then how can I remove. I have tried with various mathods but got error due to allocated pointers I think. I have tried with follow method but its not working with this kind of struct array. It is working with struct array having no pointers.

```
int DeleteStructElement(int Index, ADJP *b, int N, int at)
{
    for(int i=Index; i<N-1; i++)
        memmove(&b[i], &b[i+1], (N-at-1)*sizeof*b);     // moving the terms of array
    N--;                                                // updating new size
    return N;
}
```

Have any idea how to remove an element from my struct array?

Comment: new is C++ only which language are you using?

Comment: Your question is tagged `C` (and not `C++`), yet you're using `new`.  Are you really limited to `C`?

Comment: "new" is c++. If you are writing C you should use malloc().

Comment: of course c and c++ .. I am using visual studio C++ 2010 .. Let me tag c++ too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to delete the arrays in the deleted element to release their memory:

```
delete[] b[Index].aV;
delete[] b[Index].aT;
```

Then, you only have to do a single memmove to remove the element.

```
memmove(&b[Index], &b[Index+1], (N-Index-1) * sizeof(b[Index])
```

EDIT: as Mahmoud points out, this doesn't use the `at` parameter in `DeleteStructElement`; I'm not sure what you intended that parameter to do.

Comment: You did not make use of the parameter 'at' still I voted up because this is the right answer. Please direct him to remove the unused parameter.

Comment: thanks "nneonneo". You mean that I don't need to move all above elements? means there is no need to for loop ? just remove the Index elements and move the memory of Index+1 to index thats all ? this is what you mean ?

Comment: Well, actually, memmove is capable of moving more than one element at once, as it just moves whole blocks of memory. In this case, I've set the number of bytes (the third parameter) so that it moves all of the remaining elements.

Comment: can you also tell me is it right to copy using memcpy. like this.. 
memcpy(temp, Umb, nb*sizeof(ADJP));
in this case, we r not allocating memory for temp.aV and temp.aT, so to copy Umb memory to temp is legeal ?

Comment: memcpy is wrong since, in the original code, source and target overlap. I do not see what you want to achieve with temp.

Comment: I am coping the Umb pointer to temp, then deleting the one element from temp, after doing some procedure, again copying the temp to Umb.. ? I hope now its clear ? what would you suggest me in order to copy the pointer Umb to temp ? memcpy or by looping of each element?

Answer (score 2):

```
   int DeleteStructElement (int index, ADJP * b, int nb) {
      delete [] (b[index].aV);
      for (int i = index; i < nb - 1; ++i) {
         b[i] = b[i+1];
      }
      return nb - 1;
   }
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. Shouldn't it be: delete [] b[index].aV;  and probably also for(int i = index; i < nb - 2; ++i)

Comment: You're right with b{index]. I corrected that. Why i < nb - 2?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why I said that. Doesn't seem right now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're really using C++, a destructor in `ADJP` would be much more straightforward than `DeleteStructElement`.

But if you're doing some interesting "C" with `new`/`delete` (perhaps a well-confined subset of C++?), then I'd suggest calling `delete` from within `DeleteStructElement`.

> but got error due to allocated pointers I think

Answering this question might be much more important than others.  I'm assuming this was a runtime error? Use a debugger to suss out just exactly where the fault was.